# Is it possible to stream video from unformatted video URL in VideoView

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-videoview

My issue is - I am streaming a video from server into VideoView and URL doesn't contain file format. This URL working perfectly in browser but not working in VideoView.

If any one have faced this type of problem, please share the solution. And please don't share .mp4/3gp etc solutions. Because I am asking for without file format URL video streaming.

Thank you for reading this problem.

Comment: Can you share your url ?

Comment: yes, but it is demo URL-- http://navbharattimes.indiatimes.com/video/videodash3.cms?msid=57770978&channel=10003&videosection=videoshow&dim=0&autoplay=1&rlvideo=4901881&section=&kalstream=PROGRESSIVE%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%A8%E0%A5%8B%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%82%E0%A4%9C%E0%A4%A8&version=4

Comment: Above you mentioned not stream url

Comment: if you paste this url in web browser then it will play a video then how browser are playing this video?